# Code coverage report no longer correct after switching to private scale set agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mstest

I'm facing a weird issue. We recently moved from Microsoft hosted pipeline agents to a private scale set agent. Everything seems to work fine, all builds still run, however we have configured code coverage for pull requests, and something seems to be wrong with the coverage calculation after the switch, the coverage is way too low.

Now I checked the code coverage report. And it shows duplicate entries for the same dll (each red block in the screenshot is the same dll):

[image]

As you can see, it shows duplicate entries for **SOME** dll's, both with some impossible date behind it, and the coverage is significantly different. The Visual studio code coverage policy seems to read the coverage from the entry with the lowest coverage.

I'm at a loss at what is wrong here.

- When I leave my build yamls extactly the same, except for changing the agent pool and switch the execution of our tests to Microsoft hosted agent, the coverage is correct again.
- I checked the logs between the hosted agent and the private scale set, and they are identical (except for some generated guids and timestamps). There are no extra instances of the dll that are shown double in the log loaded.
- The date/time on the scale set instances is correct

I suspected that some remnants of other builds might be causing this issue, since our scale set agent doesn't reset itself after each build, but even with a fresh agent, the issue occurs.

**Edit**: Also, the issue seems to have something to do with combining the coverage results of multiple test tasks. We have 2 jobs that run unit tests with code coverage. When both of these jobs are run on a Microsoft hosted image, it works. When any of them is run on the scale set, the coverage issue occurs, even though only one of the 2 jobs contains tests for the assemblies that are shown double.

**Edit2**: So the plot thickens. The problem definitely has something to do with combining 2 sets of code coverage results. I have 2 test jobs, that run tests on different components, but the second set of tests also hit some methods in the libraries tested in the first set. When running the build on the scale set, azure devops seems unable to combine the two into the same coverage run. I think somehow it thinks the assemblies are 2 different assemblies. What could be the cause of this?

**Edit3**: I compared the two versions of one of the assemblies not being merged, and the assemblies seem to be identical. So it seems that the issue is somwhere in the code coverage file itself.

**Edit4:**
The build and test tasks look like this:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: "Build solution Web"
  inputs:
    solution: Web.sln
    msbuildArgs: "/p:DeployWebsite=true /p:DeployAddinsWebsite=true /p:PublishProfile=$(ApiPublishProfile) /warnaserror /p:CIBuild=true"
    platform: "${{ parameters.BuildPlatform }}"
    configuration: "${{ parameters.BuildConfiguration }}"
    clean: false
    maximumCpuCount: true
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: "Run test assemblies"
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\bin\**\*.Tests.dll'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
    runSettingsFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\testing\codecoverage.runsettings'
    testRunTitle: "WebTests"
    searchFolder: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
```

I've also checked the versions used for testing. Both the Hosted agent and the scaleset use the same `vstest.console.exe` version (16.7.0)

Does anyone have any idea to what's going on here?

Comment: Possibly timezone/regional settings causing issues? It's a wild guess, but it would also explain the weird dates. Try setting the workspace clean all option to clear the workspace to see if that helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases

Comment: I've already tested the workspace clean option to no avail. I'll dive into the timezone suggestion

Comment: alas, the date and time on the scale set instances are correct, so this doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: But what's the region and date/time format? English-US, United States for both region and date time formatting? Also for the service account of the agent?

Comment: The service account is generated by azure devops, so it's probably the same as the system itself. The time zone is UTC. Not sure about the date time formatting, I'll check tomorrow. However, I'm not really sure what to compare it to. It's not like I can set a date format in azure devops.

Comment: What are the tasks to build your project and run tests. Could you share your pipeline? It could be the different version of the test tool that caused the issue.

Comment: I can't share the entire pipeline, but I've added the build and test steps, and added the version of mstest.console.exe

Comment: https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086159-how-to-change-your-windows-services-locale

Comment: We have two build tasks (using azure devops server on-premises): unit tests and integration tests. If we deactivate one of these tasks the code coverage works. If we activate both, the assemblies which are covered by both tasks are doubled and have a future timestamp in the name. We don't know whats happening here. Could you solve the problem? We build a lot of solutions, most of them with these 2 build tasks and the problem occurres in only one single solution. It only happens since the last visual studio 2022 update on the build server. On local computers we don't have this problem.